# Protractor test a tab value

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor

Here my html sample of a list of tab

```
            <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab label="A">
                <app-A></app-A>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="B">
                <app-B></app-B>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="C"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="D"> <app-D></app-D></mat-tab>    
        </mat-tab-group>
```

I tried with protractor:

```
it('check tab D',function(){
browser.get('http://localhost:4200/');
var elems = element(by.css('.mat-tab[label="D"]'));

// expect(elems).toEqual('D');
// tab.toEqual('D');
// element(by.model('mat-tab label="D"')).click();
console.log('D exist');
```

but the results is not found. Any suggestions? I want to test if tab D exist then click on it and test if it contains some values defined in app-D
thanks

Comment: Try with  expect(elems).toExist(); and let me know if this helped you

Comment: remove the dot in css locator, should be  `'mat-tab[label="D"]'`

Comment: thanks @GajJulije but it still not working :   Message:
    Failed: expect(...).toExist is not a function

Comment: @yong thanks. when I write elems.click() I got this message :     Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, mat-tab[label="D"]) any idea?

Comment: Can you try the locator in Chrome DevTool, to see it can find desired element or not.  If yes, the locator is correct, maybe you need to wait page render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do the work

```
it('check tab D',async function() {
  await browser.get('http://localhost:4200/');
  /*
  overhere you may need to insert a waiting condition
  wait until logo is present
  wait until the welcome message is present etc
  */
  var elems = element(by.css('.mat-tab[label="D"]'));

  if (await elems.isPresent()) {
    console.log('D exist');
  }
});
```

likely, your problem is not to find out if the elem is present, you probably just need to wait until the page is fully loaded. Don't rely on builtin protractor's waiting